# Drupal Calendar, I want each user sees his own events only

Tags: drupal, calendar

I installed drupal 6 calendar module and it's working fine, but it shows all events for all users, i want to restrict that to show events for the user who already viewing now

so i want my user to see his own events only, not other users events, how can i do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding a filter in your view of `User: Current`.  That will restrict to events that the current user created.